# My php login system is not redirecting when I use the correct user and password

Tags: php, html, authentication, passwords

I've configured my database, and written my code, when i test it, and use the correct login inofrmation, the page doesn't redirect to my index.html, instead it stays on my login.php, and clear my form. No one can figure out what is wrong. all help is appreciated! The redirect function is written in functions.inc.php.

functions.inc.php

```
    <?php 
//these are the functionss that make my php run
 function redirect($page) { 
 header('Location: ' . $page);
 exit(); 
} 

// This checks if the user is logged in, it will return a boolean value, as to whether they are or not.
function check_login_status() { 
 if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) { 
 return $_SESSION['logged_in']; 
 } 
 return false; 
}
?>
```

login.inc.php

```
    <?php 
// Include required MySQL configuration file and functions 
require_once('config.inc.php'); 
require_once('functions.inc.php'); 

// Start session 
session_start(); 

// Check if user is already logged in 
if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) { 
 // If user is already logged in, redirect to main page 
 redirect('index.html'); 
} else { 
 // Make sure that user submitted a username/password and username only consists of alphanumeric chars 
 if ( (!isset($_POST['username'])) || (!isset($_POST['password'])) 
OR 
 (!ctype_alnum($_POST['username'])) ) { 
 redirect('login.php'); 
 } 

 // Connect to database 
 $mysqli = @new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, 
DB_DATABASE); 

 // Check connection 
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
 printf("Unable to connect to database: %s", 
mysqli_connect_error()); 
 exit();  }

 // Escape any unsafe characters before querying database 
 $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
 $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 

 // Construct SQL statement for query & execute 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . 
$username . "' AND password = '" . md5($password) . "'"; 
 $result = $mysqli->query($sql); 

 // If one row is returned, username and password are valid 
 if (is_object($result) && $result->num_rows == 1) { 
 // Set session variable for login status to true 
 $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; 
 redirect('index.html'); 
 } else { 
 // If number of rows returned is not one, redirect back to login screen 
 redirect('login.php'); 
 } 
} 
?>
```

login.php (this is the page the user sees)

```
    <!Doctype html>
<html>
  <head>

 <legend>Login to Web Site</legend>
</center>
 <fieldset>
 <table>
<tr>
 <td> 
 <center>
 <label for="username">
 <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />  </label>
  </center>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
  <center>
 <label for="password">
 <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/> 
 </label>
 </center>
</td>
</tr> 
 </table>
 <label for="submit"> 
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login"/> 
 </label> 
 </fieldset> 
 </form>
 </table>


    <script src="../jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Enable error display and see if you get any warnings.

Comment: , it says PHP Notice:  Undefined index: logged_in in C:\xampp\htdocs\IA\Hastler's side\login.inc.php on line 10

Comment: I don't see you actually sending any data to the server... where is the opening form tag? For that matter, where is the opening body tag?

Comment: sorry, i didnt add the form tag, stackoverflow was telling me that I couldn't add that much code

Comment: I actually didnt add any of my login.php

Comment: Based on the `Undefined index` error you reported, change `if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] == true)` to `if (check_login_status())`. See my post for full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this

```
function check_login_status() { 
 if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) { 
 return $_SESSION['logged_in']; 
 } 
 return false; 
}
```

to

```
function check_login_status() { 
  return (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) || $_SESSION['logged_in'] === true);
}
```

And your condition:

```
// Check if user is already logged in 
if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) { 
 // If user is already logged in, redirect to main page 
 redirect('index.html'); 
}
```

to:

```
// Check if user is already logged in 
if (check_login_status()) { 
 // If user is already logged in, redirect to main page 
 redirect('index.html'); 
}
```

Comment: Even though it looked like you were (barely) second in a correct response, I +1'd simply because you recommended changing the `check_login_status()` function to give a for sure `true` or `false`. Good coding IMO.

Answer (score 1):

After you call your `redirect()` function, issue an `exit`, `return`, or `die` so the code does not continue to process.

If it continues to processes and `echo`s any text, headers will already be sent and the redirect will fail. Even if you are not `echo`ing any text in this case, `exit`ing after a redirect is a good habit, as it will bite you later on in some other code.

For example:

```
redirect('index.html'); 
exit;
```

Based on your error, you should use your `check_login_status()` function. Change:

```
if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) { 
 // If user is already logged in, redirect to main page 
 redirect('index.html');
```

To

```
if (check_login_status()) { 
 // If user is already logged in, redirect to main page 
 redirect('index.html'); 
 exit;
```

This is presuming `check_login_status()` returns true when logged in.

Comment: Session vars aren't sent to the browser so output doesn't matter, as long as you start the session before you send any non-header output. The user wasn't getting a `Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent` error.